# Representation theory of algebra of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I'm trying to find all irreducible (unital: $\pi(1)$ = $1$) finite-dimensional representations of the algebra $A := \mathbb{C}[z, z^{-1}]$ of polynomials of two variables whose product is the unit, i.e. $zz^{-1} = 1 = z^{-1}z$. I came up with the following argument to show that there are no irreducible finite-dimensional representations aside from the trivial representation in $V = \mathbb{C}$.

Let $(\pi, V)$ be a representation of $A$. Since $\{z^n; n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a basis for the vector space underlying $A$, and $\pi$ is an algebra homomorphism we deduce that 1) $\pi(z)$ generates $\pi(A)$, and so it suffices to know the operator $\pi(z)$ in order to know the whole representation, and 2) $\pi(z) \in GL(V)$.

So, let $\dim V = n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\pi(z) \in GL(V)$. We put $T: V \rightarrow V$, $Tv = \pi(z)^{-1}v$ and we compute $T\pi(z)v = v = \pi(z)Tv$ so that $T$ is an invertible intertwiner between $\pi$ and the identity representation, which is only irreducible if $n = 1$.

Is this correct? If not, how can I calculate the finite-dimensional representations of the algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator $T$ is not an intertwiner to the identity representation it's just an intertwiner from $\pi$ to itself.

Recall from linear algebra that a collection of pairwise commuting complex $n \times n$ matrices is always simultaneously upper triangularizable. Therefore irreducible finite dimensional representations of this algebra are indeed one dimensional (the subspace spanned by the first columns is a one dimensional subrepresentation).

However it is not true that they are all trivial. Maps from $\mathbb{C}[z,z^{-1}]$ to any $\mathbb{C}$-algebra are completely determined by the choice of an invertible element where $z$ gets sent. In particular, one dimensional representations are given by maps from this to $End(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}$ and are just given by a choice of $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}-0$ by which $z$ acts.

Comment: indeed, you are right. I'll try to prove your assertions by myself in order to obtain the representation classification I'm looking for. As a bonus question, do you have any hints for the rep theory of the algebra C[z] of simple polynomials in one complex variable?

Comment: Roughly the same approach as above will work for that, only this time $z$ does not need to act by an invertible element.

Comment: I'll also mention that the finite dimensional indecomposable (not just irreducible) representations of $\mathbb{C}[z]$ can be completely classified as well.  This classification is more commonly known as the Jordan canonical form, it's a good exercise to work out just what I mean.

Comment: Oh my oh my! I just remembered that I was supposed to do this for the real polynomial algebra R[x]! I suppose this is a great change, since you can't use upper triangularization anymore

Comment: Ehh, things aren't actually all that different for that case. For $\mathbb{R}[x]$ you have one dimensional irreducible representations $\mathbb{R}_\lambda$ where $x$ acts by $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, and then you also have two dimensional representations $\mathbb{C}_\lambda$ where you think of $\mathbb{C}$ as a $2$ dimensional real vector space with $x$ acting by complex multiplication by $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh and I should add that $\mathbb{C}_\lambda$ and $\mathbb{C}_{\bar{\lambda}}$ are isomorphic as real representations.